# Necesito ordenar un arreglo de estructuras alfabeticamente por nombre

Tags: c++, array

Tengo un proyecto sobre un banco, donde tengo que registrar el nombre y su saldo. Estoy utilizando el metodo burbuja, pero al utilizarlo me aparece un error, me dice que no puede convertir mi arreglo de estructuras a un entero:

`Cannot convert usuarios to int in assignament.`

`Usuarios` es el nombre de mi estructura, y no encuentro la manera de solucionarlo.

```
///Ordenando Nombres
for(int i=0;i<var_gral2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<var_gral2;j++){
        if(personas[j].nombre>personas[j+1].nombre){
            aux=personas[j];
            personas[j]=personas[j+1];
            personas[j+1]=aux;
        }/**Fin if ordenamiento*/
    }/**Fin for anidado*/
}/**Fin for principal*/
```

Este es el pedazo de código donde lo ordeno

Aquí les dejo mi código completo:
Código = https://www.mediafire.com/file/7a36bhq77p6a3qn/Banco_ADS.cpp/file

Cabecera = https://www.mediafire.com/file/sjskzem0gyvxtm9/Variables.h/file

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, necesito entregar este proyecto en una semana más, gracias :)

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Lo ideal es que el código completo esté en la pregunta directamente y no en enlaces que se pueden perder o eliminar. Por favor, edita la pregunta con el contenido correcto. Revisa los siguientes enlaces que te ayudarán a conocer un poco más cómo preguntar correctamente: [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Abdiel es imperativo que leas el [tour] y tambien [ask]. Esto no es un foro, y la seccion respuestas es solo para respuesta. Si tenes nuevos problemas, debes abrir nuevas preguntas. La seccion respuestas es solo para respuestas a las preguntas. Borre todas tus publicaciones porque no tenian ningun sentido (y llegado el caso, podias dejar alguna duda puntual en un comentario). Es mas, la respuesta aceptada no es una respuesta, se deberia convertir en comentario. Si tenes alguna duda, deja un comentario aca y llamame usando @gbianchi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no se si te pueda ayudar mucho, pero existe una función que se llama sort(), que ordena las listas en orden de números o alfabéticamente.

Ademas de eso, existen más métodos de ordenamiento que el burbuja que tienen menor complejidad y son mas eficientes como el Quick-Sort.

si no mal recuerdo seria>>>

```
#include <algorithm> icluyes esta libreria

sort(personas[0], personas[hasta el final de tu arreglo]);
```

Aqui tienes la documentacion:

```
// sort algorithm example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (i<j); }

struct myclass {
  bool operator() (int i,int j) { return (i<j);}
} myobject;

int main () {
  int myints[] = {32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33};
  std::vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+8);               // 32 71 12 45 26 80 53 33

  // using default comparison (operator <):
  std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+4);           //(12 32 45 71)26 80 53 33

  // using function as comp
  std::sort (myvector.begin()+4, myvector.end(), myfunction); // 12 32 45 71(26 33 53 80)

  // using object as comp
  std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myobject);     //(12 26 32 33 45 53 71 80)

  // print out content:
  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/